# Merge two filesystem after reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I am new to Ubuntu. Recently, I reinstall my Ubuntu, and I found that the original Ubuntu system looks like this

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/nvme0n1p8   69G  4.6G   61G   7% /media/david/ec0fd309...
```

and my current system is

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5   15G  8.8G  5.4G  62% /
```

There is Windows system in `/media/david/Windows`
so i was wondering is there a way to merge the old one into new.

The result of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 288354303 287787008 137.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 288354304 320354303  32000000  15.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 320354304 352354303  32000000  15.3G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p7 352354304 352854015    499712   244M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 352854016 498069503 145215488  69.3G Linux filesystem
```

I think I need to merge the storage space in `/dev/nvmen1p8` into `/dev/nvmen1p5`

I searched and find some solution involved with GParted, but I was using the default setting to reinstall the Ubuntu, so I was thinking there might be a convenient way.
Here is the information about all the filesystem.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           775M  9.6M  766M   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   15G  9.1G  5.1G  65% /
tmpfs           3.8G  132M  3.7G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   34M  223M  14% /boot/efi
tmpfs           775M   56K  775M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p8   69G  4.6G   61G   7% /media/david/ec0fd309...
/dev/nvme0n1p3  138G   33G  105G  24% /media/david/Windows
```

[GParted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EN7S.png)

The result of `sudo mkdir /mntp7 && sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mntp7 && ls -l /mntp7`

```
➜  / sudo mkdir /mntp7
[sudo] password for david: 
➜  / ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib      lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  mntp7  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz  vmlinuz.old
➜  / sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mntp7
➜  / ls -l /mntp7
total 161417
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1246246 Apr  20 20:02 abi-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1407843 Feb   5 19:32 abi-4.8.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1408671 Apr  20 21:07 abi-4.8.0-49-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190214 Apr  20 20:02 config-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   199575 Feb   5 19:32 config-4.8.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   199588 Apr  20 21:07 config-4.8.0-49-generic
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root     1024 Apr  25 19:26 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Apr  26 19:00 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37695951 Apr  26 19:00 initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41298900 Apr  25 19:36 initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40063966 Apr  26 15:33 initrd.img-4.8.0-49-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Apr  25 19:26 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Jan  28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Jan  28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Jan  28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3883390 Apr  20 20:02 System.map-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4060748 Feb   5 19:32 System.map-4.8.0-36-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4066773 Apr  20 21:07 System.map-4.8.0-49-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7081872 Apr  20 20:02 vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7297312 Apr  25 19:27 vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7305856 Apr  20 21:07 vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7307768 Apr  25 19:36 vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic.efi.signed
```

The result of doing `vi /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=720839ca-117c-4103-91a8-c21f3b39cf7c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=908D-193B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=468d2512-9472-4d90-af6c-f38d5614be13 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The result of `sudo mkdir /mntp1 && sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mntp1 && ls -l`

```
➜  ~ sudo mkdir /mntp1 && sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mntp1 && ls -l /mntp1
ls: cannot open directory '/mntp1': Permission denied
➜  ~ cd /
➜  / sudo su
root@david:/# cd mntp1
root@david:/mntp1# ls -l
total 8
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  29 02:52 BOOT
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Apr  25 19:36 EFI
root@david:/mntp1# cd BOOT
root@david:/mntp1/BOOT# ls -l
total 3096
-rwx------ 1 root root 3170304 June  16  2016 BOOT.SDI
root@david:/mntp1/EFI# ls -l
total 12
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  29 02:52 Boot
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Mar  29 02:52 Microsoft
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Apr  27 18:45 ubuntu
```

[GParted Screenshot after adjusting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47kuk.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58054/discussion-on-question-by-david-merge-two-filesystem-after-reinstalling-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following scenario while waiting for the info on p1 and /etc/fstab.
Please don't apply the actions until we are sure to have covered everything.

**Update #1:**

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

---

```
Proposed actions per partition:
NB. Make sure there are no links in your p5 partition to p7/p8 directory or files.
If so, these must be removed.

1 /dev/nvme0n1p5
  to be expanded to larger size
2 /dev/nvme0n1p6
  Current Linux swap. Move partition to end of disk.
3 /dev/nvme0n1p7
  p7 holds grub/efi files. Move partition to right of disk.
4 /dev/nvme0n1p8
  old Ubuntu, will be deleted, space re-used.

Boot from the Ubuntu Live USB/CD and select Try Ubuntu.
Start gparted.

Right-click p8; select 'Delete'; click the green Apply sign; Apply; Close.
More unallocated space and in the graphic bar.

Right-click p7; select Resize/Move.
In the Resize/Move window click the middle of the slider; drag it to the right.
Click Resize/Move; Apply sign; Close.

Right-click p6 Linux-swap; select 'Swapoff'.
Right-click p6 Linux-swap; select Resize/Move.
In the Resize/Move window click the middle of the slider; drag it to the right.
Click Resize/Move; Apply sign; Close.
Right-click p6 Linux-swap; select 'Swapon`

Right-click p5; select Resize/Move.
In the Resize/Move window click the right arrow of the slider and enlarge to the full.
Click Resize/Move; Apply sign; Close.

Close gparted.
```

**Update #2:**

To properly prepare Windows for a dual-boot configuration with Ubuntu, do the following.

## in Windows

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: I'd recommend that you check p1 and p7. I suspect they have the same files, but p1 should have newer dates. If so, I'd just delete p7. You need a swapon for p6. You need to edit fstab to comment out the NTFS mount and remove the p8 mount. I'd give the long detail on how to disable `fast start` and hibernation in Windows, so if they do decide to mount C:, either manually or via fstab, it won't cause problems with corruption in Windows or a non-boot situation in Ubuntu. I'd also recommend that you describe the hand cursor (moves) and the arrow cursor (resizes). Otherwise, good job.

Comment: I add the information about p1 and /etc/fstab but I do not know how to do with the Windows part.

Comment: I'd leave p7 alone. fstab looks ok. still need a swapon for p6. If Willem would like me to add the raw Windows stuff to his answer, he can make it look pretty in his own style. Just let me know. Make sure to add `@heynnema` at comments directed to me or I may miss them.

Comment: Sorry about the Swapon, I missed that, fortunately the system will start without it. Thanks for spotting that. Then another matter now. I am afraid I need to have a look at my own PC as today it started with a lot of errors and a long delay. So I hope @heynnema is so kind to continue his support? Thx

Comment: @David I've added two updates to Willem's answer for you.

Comment: @WillemK @heynnema Thanks! I do not have Ubuntu Live USB available now. I will follow the instructions above tommorrow. And how can I make sure whether there are links between p5 and p7/p8. From what I understand, there should be no link as I never set links between them manually or will the `sudo mkdir /mntp7 && sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mntp7 && ls -l /mntp7` set links between them so I should cancel that?

Comment: @David the p1 and p7 commands were only used to determine what was on those partitions. No links were created. I'd prefer a Ubuntu Live DVD over a Live USB. Do your backups first.

Comment: @heynnema OK, I will do that right now. Is it ok to move some important file to the Windows partition? And it seems that the this computer do not have a DVD driver so maybe I have to use a Live USB.

Comment: @David the Windows partition isn't the best place to do that, but if you're going to do that, do **update #2** first.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I will do **update #2** and do backup on both Windows partition and a flash drive.

Comment: Hi @heynnema When I was doing                                                   
    Right-click p6 Linux-swap; select 'Swapoff'.
    Right-click p6 Linux-swap; select Resize/Move.
    In the Resize/Move window click the middle of the slider; drag it to the right.
I can't Resize/Move window graphically. What should I do next.

Comment: @heynnema @WillemK I misunderstood the meaning of  `swapoff`. Now the status of the disk is posted on the question description above. Really appreciated for your kind help.

Comment: Hi guys, I see you've made quite some progress. I see no advantage to join in again as I am going on holiday next week. Good luck !